# getcap prints `cap_dac_override=eip` instead of `cap_dac_override+eip` on CentOS8.6

Tags: linux, centos, centos8

On `CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)`, after

```
setcap 'cap_dac_override=eip' foo.sh
```

the output for `getcap foo.sh` is:

```
foo.sh = cap_dac_override+eip
```

However on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)` the output is:

```
/root/foo.sh cap_dac_override=eip
```

On CentOS8.2 the libcap.x86_64 version is 2.26-5.el8, while on CentOS8.6 the libcap.x86_64 version is 2.48-2.el8.

I couldn't find an answer on setcap/getcap's man page, this strange behavior has troubled  me for days, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: So what is the libcap version on two systems? `this strange behavior has troubled me` why?

Comment: @KamilCuk On CentOS8.2 the `libcap.x86_64` version is `2.26-5.el8`, while on CentOS8.6 the `libcap.x86_64` version is `2.48-2.el8`.